# File Explorer for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

I am developing hybrid application (POC) using Cordova and Sencha Touch 2.4, Objective is to develop file explorer.

Actually i did it using Cordova File API and I can able to access all the folders and files in Android, But in iOS i can able to read only **No Cloud** Folder (Don't know what is that folder).

I want to access complete folder structure in iOS, Just like Android.

After number of search i got info that in IOS we can't access file system using Safari browser, Is it same for Hybrid App ?

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

This is what i am doing, Using File API i am requesting file system (ROOT Folder) and when the user tap any folder, i am reading files and folders in that folder. When the user tap file i am simply showing an alert that the user selected File.

**Cordova [config.xml]**

```
    <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems"
        value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />

    <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems"
        value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
```

**Controller Code**

```
browseFs : function(button, e, eOpts){
    Ext.Viewport.add(this.getFileBrowserWindow());
    this.getFileBrowserWindow().show();
    this.getFileBrowserWindow().mask();
    this.createFileSysList(MTDProduct.app.currentDir);
},

fileBack : function(button, e, eOpts){
    this.getFileBrowserWindow().mask();
    this.createFileSysList(MTDProduct.app.parentDir);
},

createFileSysList : function(currentDir){
    console.log(currentDir);
    var me = this;
    if(!currentDir){
        currentDir = MTDProduct.app.rootFolder;
    }
    MTDProduct.app.currentDir = currentDir;
    var directoryReader = currentDir.createReader();
    Ext.getStore('filesList').removeAll();
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
        var dirArr = new Array();
        var fileArr = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<entries.length; ++i){ 
            var entry = entries[i];
            var data;
            if( entry.isDirectory && entry.name[0] != '.' ) {
                data = { name: entry.name, type: 'Directory'}
            }
            else if( entry.isFile && entry.name[0] != '.' ){
                data = { name: entry.name, type: 'File'}
            }
            Ext.getStore('filesList').add(data);
            Ext.getStore('filesList').sync();
        }

        currentDir.getParent(function(parent){ 
            MTDProduct.app.parentDir = parent; 
            me.getFileBack().show();
        }, 
        function(error){ 
            me.getFileBack().hide();
            alert('Get parent error: '+error.code);
        });
        me.getFileBrowserWindow().unmask();
    }, function(error){
        me.getFileBrowserWindow().unmask();
        alert('listDir readEntries error: '+error.code);
    });
},

fileTap : function( list, index, target, record, e, eOpts ){
    this.getFileBrowserWindow().mask();
    var data = record.getData();
    var currentDir = MTDProduct.app.currentDir;
    var me = this;
    if( data.type == 'Directory' && currentDir != null ){
        console.log('Directory');
        currentDir.getDirectory(data.name, {create:false},
            function(dir){
                me.createFileSysList(dir);
            },
            function(error){ 
                alert('Unable to find directory: '+error.code);
            }
        );
    } 
    else if(data.type == 'File' && currentDir != null){
        alert('Selected a file');

        me.getFileBrowserWindow().unmask();
        me.getFileBrowserWindow().hide();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, Apple has limited the file access to just the app itself's. So there is no other way of accessing it.

You can view files only in that your App's sandbox. Every App has got a Documents, Cache and temp folders. I think the first two are automatically backed up by iTunes when you connect your device, the latter is not backed up.

Example, to get files in Cache directory path -

```
NSError *err        = nil;
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *dirContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:&err];
if(err) NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
NSMutableArray *filePaths  = nil;

int count = (int)[dirContent count];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    [filePaths addObject:[dirContent objectAtIndex:i]];
}
return filePaths;
```

Comment: Do you know what is "No Cloud" Folder ?

Comment: Am not sure what it is.

Comment: This is wrong: "Apple has limited the file access to just the app itself's (Document directory). So there is no other way of accessing it.". There are some other folders, not just the Documents directory, you mention it later, Documents, Cache and temp (and application directory too). You should say something like "Apple has limited the file access to just your App's sandbox, Documents, Cache and temp folders"

Comment: "No Cloud" folder is a folder inside the Documents or Library folders that aren't backed up to iCloud